# When clicking below window title bar in KDE, window dragging is initiated. Can I change this behavior?

Tags: kde, window-manager, window, gtk3

this one is regarding KDE in Ubuntu 12.04.

The thing is that whenever I click below the window title bar in KDE, the window manager always assumes I want to drag the window, not just activate it. Clicking the title bar activates the window without dragging it just fine, however I sometimes find it hard to click because it's rather narrow :) Is there any way to change this behavior (besides the obvious "make your title bar larger" thing)?

I also assume this is happening to Gtk applications only (Firefox, Thunderbird, Synaptic), as I have tried it with several KDE apps (KWrite, KTorrent, Gwenview, Konsole) and noticed no such behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your "Window Behavior" settings. System Settings > Window Behavior icon > Window Behavior tab.

1) Try changing the Titlebar Actions to Activate & Raise (if it's not that already) for Inactive windows
2) You may also want to change the Window Actions tab > Inactive Inner Window > Left Button behavior

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In the Inactive Inner Window section I changed 'Activate, Raise and Pass Click' to 'Activate & Raise' and it seems to have done the trick.